# How can i add two preg_replace together?

Tags: php

How would i add both of these preg_replace together? I am lost on how to do it.

```
<?= preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '<a href="https://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>', stripslashes($row['tweet_text']))?>
<?= preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/search/$#$1">#$1</a>', stripslashes($row['tweet_text']))?>
```

and it would do both these things for

```
stripslashes($row['tweet_text']
```

Comment: not sure you can combine the regexes into one, because you're operating on two different subjects.

Comment: Yeah but i dont know php that well im working off a script i have.

Comment: Don't listen to these guys, they are both wrong, read my response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$regex = array('/@(\w+)/','/#(\w+)/');
$replace = array(
  '<a href="https://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>',
  '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/search/$#$1">#$1</a>'
);
preg_replace($regex,$replace,stripslashes($row['tweet_text']));
```

Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Also, [here's a sweet example](http://3v4l.org/aevH0).

Comment: do i put this all in one place or can i put the top part somewhere and then just call it by using `preg_replace($regex,$replace,stripslashes($row['tweet_text']));
`

Comment: The latter. You can define the arrays in the beginning of the file and use the `preg_replace` whenever you want as long as you don't overwrite the arrays.

Comment: instead of `https://twitter.com/#!/search/$#$1` use `https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23\1`

Comment: I was slow with taht one thank you so much!! 

So if i want to add http:// as well ill put `'/http://(\w+)/'` right?